# The initial control not display

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I want to extend a panel and I want to add some controls to this class. But I don't know where to put the code, if I put it in the constructor, it won't work. Let see the sample code:

```
class ExPanel : Panel {
    public Image image {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ExPanel() {
        // if I put the addPic method here, the picture will not be showed
    }

    private void addPic() {
        PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
        pic.Top = 10; pic.Left = 10;
        pic.Width = 100;
        pic.Height = 100;
        if (this.image != null) pic.Image = this.image;
        this.Controls.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

I think it because the image is set after the constructor run. But I don't know which event is appropriate to put this method.
Someone please help me, thanks

Comment: Try to add this call into `InitializeComponent()` method of your form.

Comment: You say, "the picture will not be showed".  That's because you're just creating a new PictureBox, I don't see any code that puts a picture in it.

Comment: @raven: I mean the picturebox will not be showed, I set the backcolor to blue

Comment: ... and set `pic.Visible = true`.

Comment: @HuorSwords: your way didn't work, I've just take a try. Please look the sample again. I've just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Your image property doesn't do anything.  Try this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ExPanel : Panel
{
    PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();

    public Image image
    {
        get { return pic.Image; }
        set { pic.Image = value; }
    }

    public ExPanel()
    {
        addPic();
    }

    private void addPic()
    {
        pic.Top = 10; pic.Left = 10;
        pic.Width = 100;
        pic.Height = 100;
        pic.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        if (this.image != null) pic.Image = this.image;
        this.Controls.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var foo = new ExPanel();

            Controls.Add(foo);
            foo.image =  System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\foo.jpg");
            foo.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, in my edited sample, I removed the line `pic.BackColor = Color.Blue;`. It can work with color, but Image is difference

Comment: @SmartGoat: Your image property doesn't do anything.  See my edit above.

Comment: if I add the Image through the Properties at designing time. It will not work. What event is invoked when I change the Image in Properties. That's what I am finding.